# How to reverse engineer POST request's body generation

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, http-post, data-mining

I'm trying to scrape reviews from Google Play. Google Play loads reviews dynamically after page has been scrolled to the end. I intercepted post requests that browser sends for retrieving reviews and noticed that the only thing that changes per request is the request's body. What I'm struggling to understand is how the request's body is generated.

The first request's body looked like this:

```
f.req: [[["UsvDTd","[null,null,[2,null,[40,null,\"CpUBCpIBKm0KOfc7ms0D_z7jKJielp7Fz8_Pz8_Pms3OzpuZyJvMnMXOxYmSxc3MyczPz8vIycjMysbHxszPysb__hAoITbZQaENmbWoMU2VCwWZPGwZOdccwQD8MmXEUABaCwlwT4zmNQBa2BADYMm1lu0EMiEKHwodYW5kcm9pZF9oZWxwZnVsbmVzc19xc2NvcmVfdjI\"],null,[]],[\"com.feelingtouch.zf3d\",7]]",null,"generic"]]]
```

and this's is the second request:

```
f.req: [[["UsvDTd","[null,null,[2,null,[40,null,\"CpUBCpIBKm0KOfc7msyg_28-Rpielp7Fz8_Pz8_Pm56eypyZzcycm8XOxYmSxc3MyczPz8vIycjMysbHxszPysb__hB4ITbZQaENmbWoMZI5V7V-7g3BObnBkABfM2XEUABaCwli2aizD1W9ExADYMm1lu0EMiEKHwodYW5kcm9pZF9oZWxwZnVsbmVzc19xc2NvcmVfdjI\"],null,[]],[\"com.feelingtouch.zf3d\",7]]",null,"generic"]]]
```

Can I somehow reverse engineer how the request is generated?
I tried to use Selenium, but after scrolling down few dozens time RAM usage runs up and Selenium becomes unresponsive.

Comment: My first approach would be to see if any part of the data from the second request can be found anywhere in the previous requests from the Network tool of my web browser. Otherwise, I think some browsers allow you to find the JavaScript code that triggered a request, with that you should be able to reverse engineer that.

Comment: Well, the requests do match partially,but it's just a bunch of random letters that don't seem to make any sense. I'm not that versed in scraping, I started learning Scrapy recently. I'll try to find some information regarding tracing down and debugging JS in browser. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction @Gallaecio

Answer (score 1):

The thing that changes is the pagination token. But, there are a couple of other things as well.

Here is the full encoded request body, with the parameters wrapped in `#{}` (number_of_results, pagination_token, and product_id).

```
f.req=%5B%5B%5B%22UsvDTd%22%2C%22%5Bnull%2Cnull%2C%5B2%2Cnull%2C%5B#{number_of_results}%2Cnull%2C#{pagination_token}%5D%2Cnull%2C%5B%5D%5D%2C%5B%5C%22#{product_id}%5C%22%2C7%5D%5D%22%2Cnull%2C%22generic%22%5D%5D%5D
```

So each time you scroll the page the `pagination_token` would change. They use it to retrieve the next page results.

You don't need to reverse engineer the token itself. You can find the first one when inspecting the page source, and then, for each next time you make a request to retrieve the results, the `next_page_toke` will be included in there. So, you just keep replacing the token until you reach the last page, and retrieve all the reviews.

---

Alternatively, you could use a third-party solution like SerpApi. We handle proxies, solve captchas, and parse all rich structured data for you.

Example python code for retrieving YouTube reviews (available in other libraries also):

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "SECRET_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google_play_product",
  "store": "apps",
  "gl": "us",
  "product_id": "com.google.android.youtube",
  "all_reviews": "true"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
```

Example JSON output:

```json
  "reviews": [
    {
      "title": "Qwerty Jones",
      "avatar": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJwSQC_a0OIQqkAkzuw8nAxt4vrVBgvkmwoSiEZ3=mo",
      "rating": 3,
      "snippet": "Overall a great app. Lots of videos to see, look at shorts, learn hacks, etc. However, every time I want to go on the app, it says I need to update the game and that it's \"not the current version\". I've done it about 3 times now, and it's starting to get ridiculous. It could just be my device, but try to update me if you have any clue how to fix this. Thanks :)",
      "likes": 586,
      "date": "November 26, 2021"
    },
    {
      "title": "matthew baxter",
      "avatar": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJy9NbOSrGscHXhJu8wmwBvR4iD-BiApImKfD2RN=mo",
      "rating": 1,
      "snippet": "App is broken, every video shows no dislikes even after I hit the button. I've tested this with multiple videos and now my recommended is all messed up because of it. The ads are longer than the videos that I'm trying to watch and there is always a second ad after the first one. This app seriously sucks. I would not recommend this app to anyone.",
      "likes": 352,
      "date": "November 28, 2021"
    },
    {
      "title": "Operation Blackout",
      "avatar": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjMRxVZafTAmwYA5xtamcfQbp0-rUWFRx_JzQML",
      "rating": 2,
      "snippet": "YouTube used to be great, but now theyve made questionable and arguably stupid decisions that have effectively ruined the platform. For instance, you now have the grand chance of getting 30 seconds of unskipable ad time before the start of a video (or even in the middle of it)! This happens so frequently that its actually a feasible option to buy an ad blocker just for YouTube itself... In correlation with this, YouTube is so sensitive twords the public they decided to remove dislikes. Why????",
      "likes": 370,
      "date": "November 24, 2021"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "serpapi_pagination": {
    "next": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?all_reviews=true&engine=google_play_product&gl=us&hl=en&next_page_token=CpEBCo4BKmgKR_8AwEEujFG0VLQA___-9zuazVT_jmsbmJ6WnsXPz8_Pz8_PxsfJx5vJns3Gxc7FiZLFxsrLysnHx8rIx87Mx8nNzsnLyv_-ECghlTCOpBLShpdQAFoLCZiJujt_EovhEANgmOjCATIiCiAKHmFuZHJvaWRfaGVscGZ1bG5lc3NfcXNjb3JlX3YyYQ&product_id=com.google.android.youtube&store=apps",
    "next_page_token": "CpEBCo4BKmgKR_8AwEEujFG0VLQA___-9zuazVT_jmsbmJ6WnsXPz8_Pz8_PxsfJx5vJns3Gxc7FiZLFxsrLysnHx8rIx87Mx8nNzsnLyv_-ECghlTCOpBLShpdQAFoLCZiJujt_EovhEANgmOjCATIiCiAKHmFuZHJvaWRfaGVscGZ1bG5lc3NfcXNjb3JlX3YyYQ"
  }
```

Check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-play-product-api) for more details.

Test the search live on the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?engine=google_play_product&product_id=com.google.android.youtube&gl=us&store=apps&all_reviews=true).

*Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.*